# Definition of divergent sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Prove that the statement "$(a_n)$ is divergent in $(X,d)$" is logically equivalent to $\forall a \in X, \exists \varepsilon \in (0,\infty), \forall N \in \mathbb{N}, [(n \ge N) \wedge (d(a_n,a) \ge \varepsilon)]$.

Claim: $(a_n)$ is divergent in $(X,d)$ if and only if $\forall a \in X, \exists \varepsilon \in (0,\infty), \forall N \in \mathbb{N}, [(n \ge N) \wedge (d(a_n,a) \ge \varepsilon)]$.

($\Rightarrow$) Suppose $(a_n) \in (X,d)$ whereby $\forall \varepsilon \in (0,\infty), \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \ni \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, [(n \ge N) \Rightarrow (d(a_n,a) < \varepsilon)]$.

Now $[(n \ge N) \Rightarrow (d(a_n,a) < \varepsilon)]$ is true if $\nexists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \ge N$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$; that is, a false condition means the implication is always true. However, in this case the condition is true since $0 \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $n \ge 0$. This means that $d(a_n,a)<\varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon \in (0,\infty) \Rightarrow d(a_n,a)=0$. Because $(X,d)$ is a metric space, we have $\forall x \in X, d(x,x)=0$, so $d(a_n,a)=0 \iff \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}a_n=a$. Thus $\exists a \in X$ such that $(a_n) \to a$, and hence $(a_n)$ is convergent in $(X,d)$.

$(\Leftarrow$) Suppose $\exists a \in X$ for which $(a_n) \to a$. Because $(X,d)$ is a metric space, we have that $\forall a \in X, d(a,a)=0$.
Then $\forall \varepsilon \in (0,\infty)$, we have $d(\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}a_n,a)=d(a,a)=0<\varepsilon$.

Note that for both directions I used the contrapositive.

Definition of convergent sequence: $\forall \varepsilon \in (0,\infty), \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \ni \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, [(n \ge N) \Rightarrow (d(a_n,a) < \varepsilon)]$

Does this mean that the distance between the nth term of the sequence (i.e. $a_n$) and some number $a \in X$ is $0$?

Comment: umm aren't you just meant to negate the definition of convergent? So there's actually nothing to prove here, it's just by definition.

Comment: The "statement" that is to be proven equivalent to the divergence of $(a_n)_n$ is not a sentence. The end of it, that is, $[(n\ge N)\land (d(a_n,a)\ge \varepsilon)]$ should be replaced with $\exists n\ge N\,(d(a_n,a)\ge \varepsilon).$